# How to write a SQL query that runs every 10 minutes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the 10 most searched destinations for each 10-minute interval starting at midnight i.e. 00:00:00. I am using MYSQL sever on Windows. 
Below is the structure  of the table clicklog_20:

```
  user_id     bigint(20)
  timecl      time
  action      text
  destination text
  hotel       text
```

I have written the query to give me the 10 most searched destinations with the following query:

```
select destination,count(*) 
from clicklog_20
where destination is not NULL
group by destination
order by destination desc 
limit 10;
```

Now I want to do this every 10 minutes on column **timecl** in the table. Below are sample records in the table

```
user_id             timecl      action  destination  hotel
2017032000000000129 00:18:36    Click   Berlin       SensCity Berlin Spandau
2017032000000000129 00:16:12    Click   Berlin       Azimut Berlin City South
2017032000000000129 00:05:04    Click   Cottbus      City Cottbus
2017032000000000129 00:01:50    Click   Cottbus      Ostrow
2017032000000000129 00:12:05    Click   Berlin       Days Inn Berlin West
```

I want to write a query that summarizes my table for each ten minute interval over a span of multiple hours.Is there a way to use time interval functions like DATE_FORMAT().

Comment: Use Windows' Task Scheduler and run `mysql.exe` to run the query.

Comment: If sql server just schedule SQL Server agent job to do this

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want to repeat the query every ten minutes througout each day, or whether you want to write a query that summarizes your tables for each ten minute interval over a span of multiple hours or days. You can investigate MySQL events for the former. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @O.Jones I have edited the query to answer your question. I want to write a query that summarizes my table for each ten minute interval over a span of multiple hours. Please help me if you can. Thanks!